# Apache Pig UDF no output

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, pig-udf

I'm using Apache Pig 0.15.0 on a multi-node `Hadoop` cluster. I put some of my work in Pig UDFs, written in Java. However, after `Pig` and `Hadoop` said they finished successfully, I got no output from my UDF. Moreover, some code didn't take effect at all. I use `System.out.println()` and `System.out.flush()`, but still, no output on my screen. What's possible reason of that? And how to debug at this circumstance?

Comment: welcome to SO ! please share as much details to get most help . please share your code and what is the output you expect to see. where do you expect to see your output ?

Comment: Can you share your UDF code and pigscript?

Comment: Have you checked logs of the mappers/reducers where the UDF is executed?

Comment: Please check same question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795301/pig-udf-in-displaying-result).